# A module cannot have multiple default exports in reactjs > typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following project tree

```
src
 Components
  Create
   Create.tsx
   SuccessPage.tsx
   index.ts
 index.ts
index.ts
```

Create > index.ts

```
export { default } from "./Create";
export { default } from "./SuccessPage"; // here is the error
```

Componenet > index.ts

```
export { default as Create } from "./Create";
```

Src > index.ts

```
export * from './components';
```

I want to export both pages ( create.tsx and success.tsx)
note that the pages contains 2 class

```
class Create extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
.....
}
export default Create;
```

and

```
class Success extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
.....
}
export default Success;
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change them to named exports, so you can have multiple:

```
export { default as Create } from "./Create";
export { default as Success } from "./SuccessPage";
```

Alternatively, you could keep one of them as the default export, but I doubt that's really what you want.

```
export { default } from "./Create";
export { default as Success } from "./SuccessPage";
```